# Change limit of queries in Yii2

Tags: yii2, limit

I want to create searchModel with Yii2, my query have default limit is 7, and I have an input dropdownlist on the page to switch limit of query between 7 and 30.

How I can do this?

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($modelSearch, 'limit')->dropDownlist([
        7 => '7 days',
       30 => '30 days',
    ]); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and this is Model

```
class SearchModel extend \yii\base\Models
{
    public $limit;
    public function search($params) {
        $query = Objects::find()->where(['attribute1'=>'a', 'attribute2'=>b]);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'sort' => ['attributes' => ['attribute1', 'attribute2',]]
        ]);

        $this->load($params);
        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

and this is controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
     $searchModel = new ModelSearch();
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->post());
     return $this->render('index', [
         'searchModel' => $searchModel,
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
}
```

I've tried to add

```
if(empty($params['limit'])) {
         $query->limit(7);
     }else {
         $query->limit($params['limit']);
     }
```

into the models - it worked but I think it's not a smart way to resolve it.

Comment: add your code for the search model you are using

Comment: Probably, you have to write some code. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: yeah, I just add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may define SearchModel like:

```php
<?php

namespace app\models\search;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Human;

/**
 * Class HumanSearch
 *
 * @package app\models\search
 */
class HumanSearch extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var int $limit
     */
    public $limit;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            [['limit'], 'integer', 'min' => 7, 'max' => 30], // Limit can be between 7 and 30.
            [['limit'], 'default', 'value' => 7], // Default query limit is 7 rows.
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search(array $params): ActiveDataProvider
    {
        // Initialize query.
        $query = Human::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        // Load additional params to search model.
        if (!$this->load($params) && $this->validate()) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // Set query limit.
        $query->limit($this->limit);

        return  $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

And then use it in `actionIndex()` in **Controller**:

```php
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\search\HumanSearch;

class HumanController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex(): ActiveDataProvider
    {
        $params = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams();
        $search = new HumanSearch;

        return $search->search($params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've tried it and it worked. Just a problem, default limit values wasn't set to be 7.